# AFNetworking XMLResponse body is HTML encoded and impossible to parse

Tags: ios, xml, afnetworking

The API I am trying to use is returning garbled XML when I retrieve it.
Here's the basic code to post the auth params to the endpoint.

```
[[APIManager sharedManager] postPath:@"Authenticate"
                          parameters:params
                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, XMLParser *xmlParser ) {
                                 //code
                                 NSLog(@"Raw XML Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

                             }
                             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                 //code
                                 DLog(@"error: %@", error);
                             }];
```

The response I get is garbled like so:

```
Raw XML Data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://www.morningstarsoftware.com/">&lt;MorningStar_BCE_WS&gt;&lt;MyUserInfo&gt;&lt;Tenant_Id&gt;37&lt;/Tenant_Id&gt;&lt;MsClient&gt;OBC05&lt;/MsClient&gt;&lt;Suite_Location&gt;DA&lt;/Suite_Location&gt;&lt;pseq&gt;6690&lt;/pseq&gt;&lt;CPResetAccess&gt;false&lt;/CPResetAccess&gt;&lt;CCPayor&gt;N&lt;/CCPayor&gt;&lt;CPAllowFinancial&gt;false&lt;/CPAllowFinancial&gt;&lt;CPAllowScheduler&gt;true&lt;/CPAllowScheduler&gt;&lt;CPAllowService&gt;false&lt;/CPAllowService&gt;&lt;FirstName&gt;Gary&lt;/FirstName&gt;&lt;LastName&gt;Evans&lt;/LastName&gt;&lt;OfferCC&gt;Y&lt;/OfferCC&gt;&lt;AllowACH&gt;Y&lt;/AllowACH&gt;&lt;MerchantAccount&gt;121513&lt;/MerchantAccount&gt;&lt;SQID&gt;0&lt;/SQID&gt;&lt;SQID2&gt;0&lt;/SQID2&gt;&lt;Ecom_payment_recurring /&gt;&lt;/MyUserInfo&gt;&lt;/MorningStar_BCE_WS&gt;</string>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the API just returning this incorrectly?

Comment: What's "garbled" about it?

Comment: hmm, the editor decoded the html encoded string, let me see if i can edit it to show what im actually getting in response.

Comment: there, now you can see how the "string" node is an html encoded representation of xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they've chosen to do is odd, but it isn't insane. They are returning perfectly valid XML, with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.morningstarsoftware.com/">
   Some Text
</string>
```

That is legal. And since what I've written as "Some Text" is *text*, it is correct (and required) to write any left angle brackets as the left-angle-bracket entity.

An RSS feed that includes the original HTML of a Web page works exactly the same way. My app "TidBITS News", for example, presents Web page content (in a UIWebView) that arrives in this same way, as the content of a node, entityized.

It isn't any problem, because when your XML parser asks for the content of the `<string>` element, the entities will be translated back to actual angle brackets, and you'll get a string that you can do something with. In your case what you'll do with that string is to parse *it* as XML.